# What are valid arrangments of panels for Wall of Force?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spells *Wall of Ice, Wall of Force,* and *Wall of Stone* have wording similar to:

> You can form it into a hemispherical dome or a sphere with a radius of
>   up to 10 feet, or you can shape a flat surface made up of ten
>   10-foot-square panels. Each panel must be contiguous with another
>   panel.

Yet there are some differences between the spells.  What configurations can the panels be in?  Can you make them into a box or jagged line?

This question is specifically about *Wall of Force*, but any common pattern for the "Wall" line of spells would be useful to know.

Comment: In 5e D&D, the rules for each spell are wholly contained within the spell text.  Wall spells don't *share* rules, so to speak. This should be a question about *one* wall spell, not all of them.  If you want to ask about each wall spell they should be separate questions, as each spell works differently.

Comment: @LegendaryDude I might agree with you, but the referenced text does occur in each spell description, and the mantra you reference is not wholly applicable.  The question isn't about what does the description contain, but what the text means or implies.  The accepted answer is very useful, and illustrates that *Wall of Fire* and *Wall of Thorns* fit one pattern, *Wall of Force* and *Wall of Ice* another, while *Wall of Stone* is in its own category.  Also, you are suggesting questions about general patterns are disallowed?

Comment: "In 5e D&D, the rules for each spell are wholly contained within the spell text. "   So the "in 5e" part:  you mean as opposed to other editions?  *Major Image* completely elucidated by text?  *Wall of Stone* cast on a weak battlement--what does it weigh?  Not in spell description, so it is weightless?  ETC.  "Wall spells don't share rules, so to speak:"  that is part of an answer.   So questioning your broad stroke application....

Comment: Yes, I mean as opposed to other editions such as 3.5e or Pathfinder which included rules for spells outside the actual spell text.  Not "if the spell doesn't say it it doesn't matter" such as in your example of wall of stone being weightless.

Comment: @LegendaryDude In this case, the idea of whether the elucidation is in the spell text or not is irrelevant.  If it wasn't in the spell text, then that would be referenced in the answer, as the question is "how does the spell work?"  So whether or not it is in the text of the spell description makes no difference.  Nowhere was asked a question about some general rule applicable to all "Wall" spells, so not sure where you are getting that.   It is an oft repeated point on here that isn't really helpful in all cases.

Comment: The question isn't "how does the spell work?" though.  The question in its current form is, "how do all of these different spells work?"  You have specifically asked for a rule generalizing three different spells.  This is no different than asking, "How do *fireball* and *cone of cold* work?"

Comment: @LegendaryDude OK.  I see what you are saying.  Nevertheless, practically speaking the accepted answer is the most useful to me, with the added observation in my previous comment:  *Wall of Fire* and *Wall of Thorns* are along a straight line or a in a ring; *Wall of Force* and *Wall of Ice* are planes, hemispheres, or spheres; while *Wall of Stone* can be in any connected configuration.  I am not sure how to have worded the question to elicit that observation without asking about multiple spells.  And I still haven't figured out whether *Wall of Force* can be climbed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Wall of Fire**(PHB 285)

Requirement: Must be on a solid surface

- Up to 60' long, 20' high, 1' thick along a horizontal dimension
- ringed wall up to 20' in diameter

**Wall Of Force**(PHB 285)

Requirement: Single orientation of horizontal, vertical or at an angle.

- Up to 10 10'x10' .25" thick panels arranged in any configuration along a single orientation. Panels must be contiguous.
- Hemispherical dome or sphere with a radius up to 10'

**Wall of Ice**(PHB 285)

Requirement: Must rest on a solid surface as a flat surface in default vertical orientation. There is no language similar to that of Wall of Force allowing for non-standard orientations (horizontal/angle.)

- Up to 10 10'x10'x1' panels that must be contiguous OR
- Hemispherical dome or sphere with a radius up to 10'

**Wall Of Stone**(PHB 286)

Requirements: Must merge with and be solidy supported by existing stone. If greater than 20' in length, you must halve the size of each panel to create supports.

- composed of up to 10 10'x10'x3" panels that must be contiguous with at least one other panel
- Can have any shape you desire, but cannot occupy same space as a creature or object.
- Does not have to be vertical or rest on any firm foundation.
- Can be crudely shaped to create crenellations, battlements, and so on.
- If concentrated for full duration, becomes permanent

**Wall of Thorns**(PHB 286)

Requirements: Must be on a solid surface.

- Up to 60' long, 10' high, 5' thick along a horizontal dimension
- Circle that has a 20' diameter and is up to 20' high and 5' thick

Comment: In case you wanted to add to this answer there is also *wall of light*, *wall of sand*, *wall of water*, *windwall*, and I guess *prismatic wall*