# Can a mystic use the psionic effect Wall of Wood as a floor?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, unearthed-arcana, wall, mystic

I'm playing as a 4th-level mystic (from [Unearthed Arcana: The Mystic Class](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf)). I was wondering whether I could use the Wall of Wood psionic effect (from the Mastery of Wood and Earth psionic discipline) as a floor or bridge.

It doesn't say that you can use it vertically, so I checked whether the any of the "Wall" spells could be used vertically; the only one I found that explicitly allowed this was [*wall of force*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-force).

**Can I use the walls made by Wall of Food as floors or bridges?**

Answer (score 5):

## No, it is a straight vertical wall

Unlike the [other Wall spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/96956/23024), the language used in [Wall of Wood](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf) does not offer any options of how to arrange the panels. It simply describes the wall as:

> ...60  feet long, 15 feet high, and 1 foot thick

This suggests that the Wall of Wood must be a straight wall with the only other requirement being

> at least one portion of which must be within 60 feet of you.

### Walk this way

As [Twiggy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/128967/23024) offers, if there is enough space for the wall to act as a walkway spanning a space, you could use it as a platform. The spell doesn't give requirements on a firm foundation like Wall of Stone, so it seems like it could 'float' and create a 1' wide walkway.

Comment: This seems to be an overly stringent interpretation.  There doesn't seem to be any limit to orientation in the text ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It could be, but each wall spell dictates how you can form the wall. There are no other options listed under Wall of Wood, so I went with the assumption that the listed option is the only option - especially given the precedent of the other spells listing other options. Also note that unlike Wall of Stone, if you try and close off an area with an enemy in it, they're stuck with no way to move out before it closes off.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast To me, the limit is in the dimensions; you can have one side that is very *long* and then the "15 feet high" have to go up (otherwise, it isn't high, is it), so "1 foot thick" is the only remaining horizontal dimension.

Comment: I see your point;  any rotation toward the "height" being horizontal would seem to be something to work out at a table; while it isn't restricted, it also isn't specified as an option (orientation) ... which leaves the 'plain English' rendering as you say.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe**

The Discipline may sound straight forward, but reading the Unearthed Arcana PDF wording within it for abilities similar effects are, at times, inconsistent. Here it seems to be consistent with itself with the similar Discipline ability *Ice Barrier*.

This may require a little out of the box reasoning and some convincing. The ability states "***60 feet long, 15 foot high, and 1 foot thick***". It can be argued that you can cause one end of the 60 feet to be connected to the edge of one end while other end reaches outwards towards your destination.

You may be limited to only 1 foot to walk on, which granted isn't a lot of room to work with, but what you do have is time. You have, at most, an hour of concentration to work with with one use of this ability. With ability checks to keep your balance, and going slow for the non-dex statted characters; assuming everyone makes it across at worst the one concentrating on it would probably go last and maybe have to spend the Psi Points to cast it again if everyone takes to long for some reason.

There is a bit of DM ruling on this but ultimately a lot of DMs are willing to listen and possibly consider out of the box thinking, at least in my experience anyway.

Comment: Why would you need to balance traveling across 1 foot of wood? 6 inches of wood does not require any special balancing acts, based on my own personal experience,  so why word 1 ft require this?